# Appending items to a list inside a nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of words that I want to organize in a dictionary according to the content of another list:

```
group_identifier = [1,2,1]
word_list = ['a', 'big', 'problem']
word_dict = dict.fromkeys([x for x in group_identifier], {'words': []})
for word, group in zip(word_list, group_identifier):
    word_dict[group]['words'].append(word)

print(word_dict)
```

I would like to get:

`{1: {'words': ['a', 'problem']}, 2: {'words': ['big']}}`,

but I get:

```
{1: {'words': ['a', 'big', 'problem']}, 2: {'words': ['a', 'big', 'problem']}}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: FYI, `[x for x in group_identifier]` is superfluous, just `group_identifier` would do the exact same thing. It’s already a list of items.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys - *fromkeys() is a class method that returns a new dictionary. value defaults to None. All of the values refer to just a single instance, so it generally doesn’t make sense for value to be a mutable object such as an empty list. To get distinct values, use a dict comprehension instead.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only create one list object with `{'words': []}`. Use a list comprehension to initialize the dict:

```
word_dict = {k: {'words': []} for k in group_identifier}
```

This initializes an individual list for each key.

Comment: Amazing, that solved it. Thank you!!